# Why should I use my own TimerQueue when I can use the default one?

Tags: c++, winapi

What advantages do I have from making my own `TimerQueue` by calling `CreateTimerQueue` and using it rather than just calling `CreateTimerQueueTimer` with a `NULL` value for `TimerQueue` and thus using the default one? I understand that if I use my own I can delete all the timers at once by deleting the queue. I can hardly imagine that this is the only advantage, what am I missing?

Comment: Only thing I could think of is it allows you to compartmentalize your timers between program modules since there's no risk of another module deleting all timers in the default queue and blowing yours away. I'm curious if anybody else comes up with a better reason though.

Comment: @HerrJoebob I am too, thats why I asked the question ;) We enforce RAII management of that kind of thing so the "protect yourself from others" aspect is a non issue for us.

Comment: For the same reason you might choose a private heap instead of the default process heap: It lets you put all your timers in a private queue where it won't be interfered with by other timers. For example, another component might flood the default timer queue with a bajillion timers, starving out your timers. This is not normally something one worries about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thanks to HerrJoebob and Raymond Chen for their quality comments. I did not originally intend to answer my own question.

Reason 1: someone else deleting all timers in the default queue (thanks to HerrJoebob)

Reason 2: someone else putting a 'bajillion' (slang for very many) timers in the default queue and starving yours (thanks to Raymond Chen)

Reason 3: using the flag `WT_EXECUTEINTIMERTHREAD` saves a context switch when executing the callback, however if the callback takes a while it delays other timers. Using your own TimerQueue means you have your own timer thread so no one else can delay your timers and you can't inadvertently delay someone else's.